# Entity Framework Database first with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Ok I tried Searching for this but didn't find it, maybe it is there but im not sure

Lets say I have a database and I use Database first with Entity Framework

It generates code for me but it useses `new List<>();`

How Can I change this so Entityframework generates `new ObservableCollection<>();` instead of List<>

My WPF Binding depends on this :)

Kind Regards